# Workflow to update field 1 of Opportunity triggered by field 2 of Task

Tags: workflow

I'm new to workflow, so I'm not sure if this is a basic question although I did some poking around and dabbling for a couple hours.

The trigger field here is **Subject** of Object Task. When the subject field value changes to "Sub1" (example), I need the field **Stage** of Opportunity for Account_ABC to change to "Stage1" automatically.

How can I achieve this using Workflows - a brief step by step would be great. Or do I need to use something else such as Apex triggers for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update Account based on Task workflows. You can only do cross object field updates when there is a master detail relationship. See this [info on cross-object field updates.](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm)

You could do it with a trigger, but that can be very difficult to write correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you help me understand how I can proceed please? In the link you shared, I think what I need is "Standard Object to Standard Object". What option under this does my question pertain to - "Opportunity updating Account"? I still don't know how I can update the Opportunity stage field based on the Task subject.

Comment: You must write a trigger on the Task object. There is no way to do it with workflow rules.

Comment: It seems like it would be a monumental task for me to get this trigger to work. Could you get me rolling in the right direction by providing some links, tips, guidance? If I get stuck, and I'm pretty sure I would, I'll post a separate question on the trigger, but until then, something to get started. Thanks.